# When conditional from ssh command line in Ansible Role

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible so any help would be appreciated.
I need to check if my remote Centos Servers have a writable /boot before I try and push VMware tools to them . Install will fail if it's read-only . How do I add another WHEN for this raw Linux command? I know if have to use register or standard out, but I cannot find examples to guide me .

```
RAW Linux Would be >  
 mount | grep boot
```

And I need to catch rw, the target must not be ro like in this example

```
> 
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (ro,relatime,data=ordered)
```

I tried adding a task under the block like in the ansible documentation.

```
- name: Catch Targets with read only boot

  tasks:

      - command: mount | grep boot
        register: boot_mode

      - shell: echo "motd contains the word hi"
        when: boot_mode.stdout.find('ro') != -1



---
- name: Wrapper for conditional tasks 
  block:  
  - name: Copy Files from Mirror to Remote Guest
    get_url:
      url: "{{ item }}"
      dest: /tmp
      owner: root
      group: root 
    with_items: 
      - http://mirror.compuscan.co.za/repo/vmwaretools65u2/CentOS7/VMwareTools-10.3.5-10430147.tar.gz

  - name: UnTAR the installer 
    unarchive:
      src: /tmp/VMwareTools-10.3.5-10430147.tar.gz
      dest: /tmp
      remote_src: yes

  - name: Run the PL install
    become: yes
    command: /tmp/vmware-tools-distrib/vmware-install.pl -d

  - name: Perform Clean Up 
    file:
      state: absent
      path: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: 
      - /tmp/vmware-tools-distrib/
      - /tmp/VMwareTools-10.3.5-10430147.tar.gz

  - name: Report on success or failure
    service:  
      name: vmware-tools
      state: started
      enabled: yes 

  when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' and ansible_distribution_major_version == '7'
  ignore_errors: yes
```

I want the role/playbook to ignore Targets in read-only /boot mode.

Answer (score 3):

Put [stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html#stat-retrieve-file-or-file-system-status) task in front of the block

```
- stat:
    path: /boot
  register: boot_mode
```

Then add the condition to execute the block if /boot is writeable

```
  when:
    - boot_mode.stat.writeable
    - ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'
    - ansible_distribution_major_version == '7'
```